# How to get result of two querys in the same result within SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that give me the result.
What I am trying to achieve is to get the result of the first query on the top (as the first value), and then the results of the second query under that, so the exact result will come first (`Inlagg.Categori = 'testcategory'`), and then if there is more results with the `LIKE 'testcategory%'` show them under and order them after amount of categories.

How do I match these queries together?

```
SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount' FROM Inlagg 
WHERE Inlagg.Date > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Categori = 'testcatego'
GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date

SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount' FROM Inlagg 
WHERE Inlagg.DatE > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Kategori LIKE 'testcatego%'
GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: do you have a column `Inlagg.Kategori`and a column `Inlagg.Categori`or is that a typo? and if its a typo, do you know that you'll find `Categori = 'testcatego'`with `LIKE 'testcategory%'`too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Parado's answer is in right way nad you need to `ORDER BY amount DESC`
I suggest you this query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount', '0' As Ord
    FROM Inlagg 
    WHERE Inlagg.Date > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Categori = 'testcatego'
    GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount', '1' As ord
    FROM Inlagg 
    WHERE Inlagg.Datum > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Kategori LIKE 'testcatego%'
    GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date ) DT
ORDER BY ord, amount DESC
```

Trick: **ord** will keep the number of the query.

Comment: Thanks alot! works! is it also possible to remove the row from the second query that will be the same as in the first query which picks the exact word? to deny getting that row twice? anyhow thanks!

Comment: @mattias By using `AND Inlagg.Categori <> 'testcatego'` before `GROUP BY` in the second query ;).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `UNION ALL` as below

```
SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount' FROM Inlagg 
WHERE Inlagg.Date > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Categori = 'testcatego'
GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date
UNION ALL
SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount' FROM Inlagg 
WHERE Inlagg.Datum > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Kategori LIKE 'testcatego%'
GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date
```

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'." this should work in sql server?

Comment: @mattias Yes of course! Did you copy my code without changes?

Comment: Nah i have the same issue, cant figure out why, if i run it without union all i get the result in two different views, but with the union all i get the syntax error, EDIT: can i use where statement in both?

Comment: Appearently i cant use ORDER BY before union all, but how can i get the result of the first select to be the first row even tho I'd like to have a order by to the second select? because the results of the second select statement gets first in the list of rows atm

Comment: @mattias No you can't use `order by` this is the reason why I removed it :), to order it you can use  shA.t's solution

Answer (score 0):

just write one simple query and sort the testcat on top :

```
SELECT Inlagg.Categori, COUNT(Inlagg.Categori) AS 'amount', '1' As ord
FROM Inlagg 
WHERE Inlagg.Datum > '2015-04-26' AND Inlagg.Categori LIKE 'testcatego%'
GROUP BY Inlagg.Categori, Inlagg.Date
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Inlagg.Categori = 'testcatego' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         Inlagg.Date
```

the case checks if the categori is equal and translates it to 1. otherwise its 2.